# When Upload files create a folder for a document to go into PHP

Tags: php, forms

Basically, when a user uploads a file on my form, i wont it to make a new folder within the docs folder, then  inside that folder place the document they uploaded.

**For example:**

Main folder = docs/

if a user uploads a document i want it to look like this:

**docs/1/document.jpg**

so it creates the folder 1 in the docs folder and puts the file in. However with my code so far, it is creating the folder 1 in the docs folder correctly. But the actual document does not go inside the 1 folder it goes to the root directory.

**Result from my code**

Docs/1

document.jpg

Its not inside the docs file but the actual root directory.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$number = 1;

$target_dir = "docs/";
$target_file = mkdir($target_dir . $number . "/") . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: You are not passing the correct path in **move_uploaded_file()** ? I think it should be $target_dir . $target_file .. ?

Comment: This does not work, if i put (move_uploaded_file($target_dir . $target_file) i get Warning: move_uploaded_file() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\test\upload.php on line 41.  although it does create the folder 1 just not input the file there

Comment: and if i then put a comma instead of . like ($target_dir , $target_file) i get Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

Comment: move_uploaded_file(YOUR_FILE , $target_dir . $target_file); Try to understand the code you copy paste form somewhere... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$target_dir = "docs/";
$target_file = mkdir($target_dir . $number . "/") . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

to this

```
$target_dir = "docs/";
mkdir($target_dir . $number . "/");
$target_file = $target_dir . $number . "/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

`mkdir` return value is a boolean.

Comment: when i do that it doesnt work. It creates the folder and then puts the image in the docs folder not the new folder called 1

Comment: Yes, my fault. I forgot to concat the number to the target file. Check my edited answer.

Comment: that works with only one file being uploaded, i just noticed when i try to upload 2 files at the same time it only places the 2nd input file into the folder.

Comment: If you want to upload 2 files, then you need to loop through on the `$_FILES` array, and move all of them one by one.